# No_Data_found exception in oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql

i have two database table(account and account1).I want to input a account number and first check if the 
account number is in the account table or not.if it is not in the account table then raise an exception and check the account1 table.the code works for this. but if i want to show a error message if the account number also not found in the account1 table then what should i do.
here is my portion of code-

```
BEGIN
begin
select Balance,Cid
    into cur_balance,cl_id
    from Account 
    where Accno = x;
    select max(Tid) into id from(select Tid from trnsaction union select Tid from trnsaction1);
    id:=id+1;
    ac_branch := 'mirpur';
exception
    when no_data_found then
    select Balance,Cid
    into cur_balance,cl_id
    from account1
    where accno = x;

    select max(Tid) into id from(select Tid from trnsaction union select Tid from trnsaction1);
    id:=id+1;

    ac_branch := 'gulshan';         

end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not `union all` and `row_number`?

```
begin
Select Balance,Cid, branch
into cur_balance,cl_id, ac_branch
from
(Select Balance,Cid, branch
       row_number() 
       Over (order by seq) as rn
From   
(select Balance,Cid, 1 as seq, 'mirpur' as branch
    from Account 
    where Accno = x
Union all
select Balance,Cid, 2 as seq, 'gulshan' as branch
    from account1
    where accno = x))
Where rn = 1;
    select max(Tid) into id from(select Tid from trnsaction union select Tid from trnsaction1);
    id:=id+1;
exception
    when no_data_found then
    Null; -- or dbms_output.put_line('acct not found');
end;
/
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> `raise_application_error(-20001,'None of the tables contain this account !');`
>   **or**
>
> `dbms_output.put_line('None of the tables contain this account !');`

within the last raised exception statement for the `Account` tables :

```
DECLARE
  cur_balance  Account.Balance%type;
  cl_id        Account.Cid%type;
  id           trnsaction.Tid%type;
BEGIN
  begin
        select Balance, Cid
          into cur_balance, cl_id
          from Account
         where Accno = x;

        ac_branch := 'mirpur';
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        select Balance, Cid
          into cur_balance, cl_id
          from Account1
         where accno = x;

      ac_branch := 'gulshan'; 

        exception
          when no_data_found then 
            raise_application_error(-20001,'None of the tables contain this account !');           
  end;     

  begin
      select max(Tid)
        into id
        from (select Tid
                from trnsaction
              union
              select Tid from trnsaction1);
      id := id + 1;

     exception
       when no_data_found then null;           
  end;    
END;
```

where column types of `Account` vs. `Account1`, and `trnsaction1` vs. `trnsaction` tables are considered to be identical, relatively.

If you prefer using `dbms_output.put_line` then issue the command `set serveroutput on` before it.

*Btw, no need to repeat the other query which's independent from our interested queries.*